# express.session undefined in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, rest, api, express

I am very new to typescript/javascript, I am trying to build backend rest apis with `session`
following is **app.ts** file

```
import express from "express";
import { applyMiddleware, applyRoutes } from "./utils";
import routes from "./services";

const app = express();

    var ses= {
        secret: "secret_session",
        resave: true,
        saveUninitialized: true,
        cookie: { maxAge: 3600000,secure: false, httpOnly: true
}
if (app.get('env') === 'production') {
    app.set('trust proxy', 1)
    ses.cookie.secure = true
}

app.use(session(ses));

applyRoutes(routes, app);
```

I have started the server and applied the middlewares for `error handling` but those are not related to question in my opinion so I'm not adding code for it. Following is my **routes.ts** code where I'm trying to set the session.

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import { getAll, getByKeyword, addNewProduct } from "./productControllers";
{
path: "/api/v1/getAllProducts",
method: "get",
handler: [
  (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    getAll()
      .then((row: any) => {
       var sess = req.session;
       sess.views = 1;
        res.status(200).json({ data: row });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.json({
          message: err
        });
      });
  }
]
}
```

I'm getting error at **sess.views = 1;**

I have tried the suggested questions before asking it, none of them were of any help to me.

EDIT:
I have created an **index.ts**

```
import searchRoutes from "./products/routes";

export default [...searchRoutes];
```

I have another util class

```
export const applyRoutes = (routes: Route[], router: Router) => {
  for (const route of routes) {
    const { method, path, handler } = route;
    (router as any)[method](path, handler);
  }
}
```

Comment: Reading `express-session` docs I've encounter the following, which may be relevant:

"Be careful when using this setting if the site is available both as HTTP and HTTPS, as once the cookie is set on HTTPS, it will no longer be visible over HTTP".

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @hurricane it gives object is possibly undefined for sess variable

Comment: Where did you define your routes? You should define your routes after `app.use(session(ses))`. Could you update your code to show us where do you use routes.ts?

Comment: It is good but still, I am not able to see do you run applyRoutes(routes, app) after app.use(session(ses)); or not? Where does the`app` variable coming from?

Answer (score 3):

You are using an interface which is `Request` for express.js. But it doesn't have type definition for `session`. So typescript throws a compile error. To solve it you need to define session type under Request interface.

You could define a session.d.ts file under your project. And create required types & interfaces. Like:

```
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Request {
      session?: Session;
      sessionID?: string;
    }
  }
}

interface Session{
  mySessionVarible:string
}
```

But the good thing is we have DefinitilyTyped project which you can find many type definitions. This needs to solve your compile problem.

```
npm install --save-dev @types/express-session
```

And don't forget to change your import for Request.

```
import { Request, Response } from "@types/express-session";
```

Comment: I'm sorry but it's not working even if I changed `declare global` to `export declare module global` it is not able to find the module

Comment: Just try to install @types/express-session without writing any code.

Comment: I have installed it.

Comment: @rookieDeveloper use `import { Request, Response } from "@types/express-session";`

Comment: `Module '"../../../node_modules/@types/express-session"' has no exported member 'Response'.`

Comment: @hurricane Are you providing wrong information ? I have same issue as @rookieDeveloper. `import { Request, Response } from "@types/express-session";` produces `Module '"../../../node_modules/@types/express-session"' has no exported member 'Response'.`

Comment: I'm having the same issue any did anyone managed to figure it out?

Comment: @tosh installing @types/express-session would help.